# UIImage imageNamed memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to understand why I have memory leaks in a very basic implementation of a UIImage and a UIImageView.

I am not using ARC in that case (correctly disabled).

My code is pretty straightforward :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

I am implementing this code in the `viewDidLoad:` method of a UIViewController.

By calling the method `imageNamed:` of UIImage, I know that I will get an object that I do not own / an autorelease object. This object will also be retained by the UIImageView object instantiated just after. So the only object I have the ownership is the UIImageView one.

After running this app with the Memory Leaks Instruments, I have this report :

[image]

I heard about the cache system that operates but I should not have have memory leaks because some datas are cached.

Here is a reference to the answer with the cache explanation :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930567/1154501

Thank you in advance !

Edit : Tried also with ARC, and I got the same issue.

Comment: i'd be curious to know if the same leak happens when using ARC

Comment: I just tried and I have the same issue with ARC

Comment: I guess this is an issue with the Memory Leaks Instrument. The code analyzer sometimes has some issues, too. :)

Comment: Your code sample is correctly handling the memory issues. The only "issue" is that `imageNamed` will cache the image, so if it's an image that you don't need repeatedly throughout your app, you should really use `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

Comment: I might be missing something but why do you think the leak is caused by `imageNamed:`?

Comment: I'm not saying that's the cause of the leak. I'm saying that `imageNamed` will cache images, and so if you're looking at allocations, you won't see the memory freed for the image until the cache is cleared due to memory pressure. But the leak is something else. Frankly, I think it's an (annoying) internal iOS thing, not your code, and given that the amount of memory involved is negligible, I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. If you're worried about memory use, the use of `imageNamed` is more of an issue (unless you definitely wanted it cached) than the modest reported "leak".

Comment: I doubt that there is a leak.

Comment: should not an `[image release];` line be somewhere here...?

Comment: just a little comment for your OP, the ARC for an iOS project nowadays should be _correctly enabled_, not disabled...

Answer (score 9):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` is managed by the operating system. Deallocating the UIImage created from this method might free up the memory that was allocated. If you have lots of images or user generated content, you should be using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` or `[UIImage imageWithData:]`.

If you create too many images with [UIImage imageNamed:], your app may get killed by iOS because of memory usage. I made a sample app to prove this to myself, see more here: [iOS UIImage storage formats, memory usage and encoding / decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588338/ios-uiimage-storage-formats-and-memory-usage)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why this operation is managed by the OS ?

Comment: That's just what apple says. They refer to the system cache here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to open the 'Extended Detail' right panel and look for the exact line where the memory is leaking?

Your code is OK, my opinion is that the leak is somewhere else.