# Removing objects from memory when switching storyboard scenes

Tags: memory, swift, storyboard

I am creating all of my display objects programatically and adding them to my storyboard scenes subview.

For example:

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton( frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 50 ) )
self.view.addSubview( button )
```

When changing storyboard scenes, I am experiencing huge memory leaks (memory usage almost doubling between every scene change), which of course shows that these objects are not being removed automatically when changing scenes. I have read some things about garbage collection in Swift, but didn't find much info on this particular use case.

By changing storyboard scenes, I mean via present view controller, like so:

```
self.presentViewController( targetController, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

So with that said, my question is:

1) Removing objects can be done like so:

```
button.removeFromSubview()
button = nil
```

correct?

2) Is there a way to remove any object inserted into the view's subview in a loop and also assign it to nil to completely remove any references associated with the object? I can remove them one by one, but it's a pain staking task.

3) Is there anyway to get objects removed automatically from memory after changing scenes? This would be the best solution.

An example of a solution would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you adding the subviews? viewDidLoad? viewDidAppear? init?

Comment: In viewDidLoad. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some things that might be clarifying:

1) Buttons that are added via storyboard (those tagged @IBOutlet) are weak; you do not need to nil them out, because your reference to them doesn't keep them in memory.

2) `presentViewController` probably doesn't behave in the way you expect. Most importantly, doesn't *replace* the existing view controller with the new view controller; it "presents" the new view controller *from* the old view controller. To illustrate this, you can call `self.presentingViewController` from the new view controller, which will provide you with a reference to the previous view controller; it's still in memory.

However, view controllers aren't super big, and they have their views unloaded when they aren't on screen. If however you are holding on to some large resources in the presenting view controller, these will persist. I would suggest addressing this by loading those assets in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear (instead of viewDidLoad) and then unloading them in either prepareForSegue: or viewDidDisappear (I think there's some long-standing issue with didDisappear not getting called consistently? I have some sort of mental flag around there but I'm not sure what the source is...)

*Alternatively*, if what you actually want to do is to fully change to a new root view controller, you can do this through your AppDelegate's .window property, like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named: "NewStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let newVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window.rootViewController = newVC
```

I wouldn't overuse this, though; it's mostly useful in places where you maybe show a tutorial on first launch, and then afterwards want to load the normal view hierarchy.

Comment: This is close to the answer I am looking for. To elaborate further, i do not create anything via storyboard, everything is created programatically aside from my view controllers (i add them to story board and instantiate them were needed.                                 As for unloading the objects, in this scenario, is looping through the subviews enough? What about their references? Do i need to add each object to an array so i can loop through and nil them after? Same question goes for any variables that are part of the view controller class. I would love a method to just dump everything

Comment: To add to my above comment, looping through the subviews doesn't seem to be enough, I still get a memory leak after changing between scenes repeatedly. Which is my reason for asking how other people clear their references also, when working with programatically created objects exclusively. In other frameworks I have used, it was standard practise to nil references after removing the objects, but was possible by looping through subviews, removing the objects and nilling it's reference, hence my confusion :)

Comment: the view controller's view is unloaded when the view is no longer visible. It's possible that your leak is related to images being kept in the system cache; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588338/ios-uiimage-storage-formats-memory-usage-and-encoding-decoding.

Comment: That could be a possibility for sure. However, to get a better grasp of my question.. in objective-c for instance, you can get rid of an object by doing the likes of: [object release]; object = nil  -  Is there no Swift equivalent ? If it handles all this internally then great, but I am still unsure from the answers given. Your responses so far have been helpful however. Thanks

Comment: in objective-c with ARC enabled you should not be able to call `release`. Objects are deallocated automatically when their reference count drops to zero; to deallocate you should just make sure that you have no references to the object. If an object is still in memory, it means that someone somewhere is holding on to a pointer to it. Take a look at Apple's [memory management programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW1) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

If by changing scenes you mean that you are adding a new view to the stack, then it is my understanding that the previous view remains there just waiting to be popped to the top of the stack again and therefore your objects should not be removed. Someone will correct me if I have this wrong. Regardless, the code to remove all of the objects from a view is:

```
for sv in view.subviews {
    sv.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: I have added further info. From my testing, in my use case that doesn't clear the memory as there are still references to the object(s), It naturally removes them from display however. I did try this approach prior to posting, but not being able to nil the objects didn't help. Thanks