# Freeing memory after UIImage call

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have the following code snippet that's called everytime I push a different button.

The problem is that everytime the function is called, new memory is used and after a while I have a memory warning.

**image** is local variable of class where changeTexture is called.

Any suggestion how to avoid memory lost/warning ?

```
func changeTexture(textureNumber: Int)
{
    image = UIImage(named: ("Texture" + String(textureNumber)))
    textureViewImage.image = image
}
```

Comment: This might be relevant to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588338/ios-uiimage-storage-formats-memory-usage-and-encoding-decoding

Comment: `UIImage(named:)` caches. If you don't want that, don't use it.