# Reducing peak memory consumption

Tags: objective-c, memory

I generate bitmaps using the next simplified for the sake of simplicity code:

```
for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < 90; frameIndex++) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(130, 130));

    // Making some rendering on the context.

    // Save the current snapshot from the context.
    UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.snapshots addObject:snapshot];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

So nothing non-trivial but everything gets complicated when an operating system gives about 30 MB of memory for everything (in this particular case it is watch OS 2 but nevertheless it is not the OS-dependent question) and by exceeding the quota, the OS just kills the application's process.

The next graph from the Allocations Instrument illustrates the question:

[image]

It is the same graph but with different annotations of memory consumption -  before, at the moment and after the aforementioned code execution. As it can be seen about 5.7 MB of bitmaps have been generated eventually and it is the absolutely acceptable result. What is not acceptable it is memory consumption (44.6 MB) at the peak of the graph - all of this memory is eaten by `CoreUI: image data`. Given the fact that the action takes place in a background thread the time of execution is not that important.

So the questions: What is the right approach to decreasing memory consumption (maybe by increasing the execution time) to fit the memory quota and why the memory consumption is increased despite `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` is called?

**Update 1:**
I think splitting the whole operation by using NSOperation, NSTimer etc. will do the trick but still trying to come up with some synchronous solution.

Tried to gather all answers together and tested the next piece of code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(130, 130));
for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < 45; frameIndex++) {

    // Making some rendering on the context.

    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [self.snapshots addObject:snapshot];
    }
    CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(130, 130));
}

for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < 45; frameIndex++) {

    // Making some rendering on the context.

    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        [self.snapshots addObject:snapshot];
    }
    CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGSizeMake(130, 130));
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What has changed:

1. Split 90 iterations into 2 parts of 45.
2. Moved a graphic context outside and clear it after each iteration instead of creating new one.
3. Wrapped taking and storing snapshots in the autorelease pool.

As a result - nothing changed, memory consumption remains on the same level.

Also, if remove taking and storing a snapshot  at all it will decrease memory consumption only for 4 MB i.e. less than 10%.

**Update 2:**

Doing rendering by a timer every 3 seconds generates the next graph:

[image]

As you see memory is not freed (to be precise - not fully) even if rendering is divided by time intervals. Something tells me that memory is not freed until the object that performs rendering exists.

**Update 3:**

The problem has been solved by combining 3 approaches:

1. Splitting the whole rendering task into subtasks. For example, 90 drawings are split into 6 subtasks by 15 drawings in each (The number of 15 was found empirically).
2. Executing all subtasks serially using `dispatch_after` with the small interval after each (0.05s in my case).
3. And the last and the most important. To avoid the memory leak like on the last graph - each subtask should be executed in a context of a new object. For example:

   `self.snapshots = [[SnaphotRender new] renderSnapshotsInRange:[0, 15]];`

Thanks to everyone for answering but @EmilioPelaez was closest to the right answer.

Comment: why not creating a timer which calls each second your method which generates an image ?

Comment: The easiest way to decrease memory consumption is to decrease the size of generated image (self.contextSize)  which is captured from the context

Comment: The total byte size of the images could be 130 * 130 * 4 (bytes per pixel) * 150 = ~10MB. Not to sure about the watch but temporary memory might be building up, you could try wrapping `UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`
    `[self.snapshots addObject:snapshot];` in an `@autoreleasepool` block.

Comment: ... also, why not move `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext` outside the loop? Clearing a context isn't hard, and you'd definitely not then have 150 times whatever processing and autoreleased cost there is of that, regardless of whether you establish your own transient pools.

Comment: Are you using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` or `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`? In the first case, which scale factor are you using?

Comment: @Tommy Moving creation of a context outside the loop and clearing the context in the end of the each iteration didn't produce the effect.

Comment: @FranMowinckel I think it's not important. The number of generating bitmaps and their resolution can vary - it's not the point.

Comment: @azimov I think playing with timers can be one of the approaches but it looks a little bit tricky. And it's still not clear where the peak on the graph comes from.

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak I notice that the graphs are not real in that they are copies of the same graph just with different annotations. Why bother providing them if they are not accurate?

Comment: @zaph But I mentioned that in the question "It is the same graph of memory consumption but in different moments of time". Just wanted to show 3 different annotations, sorry if it's not that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are doing all the snapshots in the same context (the context the `for` loop is in). I believe the memory is not being released until the context ends, which is when the graph goes down.

I would suggest you reduce the scope of the context, so instead of using a for loop to draw all frames you would keep track of the progress with some iVars and draw just one frame; whenever you finish rendering the frame, you can call the function again with a `dispatch_after` and modify the variables. Even if the delay is 0, it will allow the context to end and clean up the memory that is no longer being used.

PS. When I mean context I don't mean a graphics context, I mean a certain scope in your code.

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak I saw your edit and I don't think it will change anything because it's all still happening within the same context. Even worse, autorelease pools err on the side of caution and will hold onto your objects for longer than regular memory management. Have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: Updated the question. Even dividing by time intervals doesn't do the trick, unfortunately. Think `disptach_after` is using the same underlying principles as `NSTimer`.

Comment: Emilio thanks. I've updated the question with the final outcome.

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

*Corrected the to the updated question frame count.*

The total byte size of the images could be 130 * 130 * 4 (bytes per pixel) * 90 = ~6MB.

Not to sure about the watch but temporary memory might be building up, you could try wrapping the snap shot code in an `@autoreleasepool` block:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.snapshots addObject:snapshot];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Forgot to mention that I've tried to wrap the whole loop in the `autoreleasepool` block but the memory consumption remains on the same level. Was a little bit in hurry and yes your size calculation is right - I corrected the code, the real number of tested bitmaps is 90, so it's about 6 MB as on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

wait, image resolution plays a big role, for example, a one mega byte jpeg image of the dimensions 5000 px * 3000 px would consume ram of size of 60 MB, 5000*3000*4 bytes are 60 MB, images get decompressed into the ram, so let's troubleshoot, so first, please tell us what kind of image sizes (dimensions) do you use ?

Comment: Updated the question with the number of bitmaps which were used in graph generating.

Comment: could you update us with the image resolutions (dimensions) you use? what is the value of self.contextSize ?

Comment: **tip 1 :** try make it by 5 meals, i mean do 5 for loops, first one has 30 images, **let it finish** then make the other iterations until you finish, the final ram could be the same, but the peak can go down.

**tip 2 :** if you don't use alpha in the image turn it off.

**tip 3 :** try writing the image on the watch memory as files instead of ram, temporarily, you can consider these temp files, this depends on the use.

Good Luck, i don't know if i can help further.

Comment: This answer should have been posted as a comment. However the last comment seems to answer the question, @Zazu could you update your answer? Otherwise it's not really an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question with the new example using your tips as well. But the problem is still here. It seems there is no synchronous solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (after clarifications):

I think, that the proper way should be not to store `UIImage` objects directly, but compressed `NSData` objects (i.e. using 
`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`). And then, when need it, convert them again to `UIImage` objects.

However, if you use many of them simultaneously, you're going to run out memory quite rapidly.

Original answer:

Actually the total size can be higher than 10MB (probably > 20MB) depending on the scaling factor (as seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html)). Note that the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` requires a scale parameter in contrast to the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. So my guess it's this is somehow related to a screenshot isn't it?

Also the method `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` [it's thread safe](http://UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext), so it might be returning a copy or using more memory. Then you have your 40MB.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588338/ios-uiimage-storage-formats-memory-usage-and-encoding-decoding) states that iOS somehow stores the images compressed when not displayed. This can be the reason to the 6MB of usage afterwards.

My final guess is that the device is detecting a peak of memory and then tries to save memory somehow. Since the images are not being used, it compressed them internally and recycles memory.

So I wouldn't worry because it looks like it's taking care of it by itself. But then you can do as others have suggested, save the image into a file and don't keep it in memory if you're not going to use it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The 6MB of usage afterward that's what I need the problem is in exceeding the memory limit of 30MB (watch OS). Think you didn't get the question right. Updated it. Are there any alternatives to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`?

Comment: Ok, then instead of storing `UIImage` objects you could try storing directly a compressed reference to its data, like for example using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. You could create an `UIImage` directly when needed from that `NSData` object.

Comment: Thanks but as I wrote above if even remove storing `UIImage` at all it will reduce the memory consumption less than for 10%. So the problem is somewhere at the graphic context creating stage.